# Profiler под Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-studio

Использую Android studio 3.4.1 
Как можно посмотреть мониторинг ресурсов для Android 4.4?

Штатный Profiler не предназначен для 4.4 (

Comment: старую версию студии установи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно получится запустить monitor из консоли (директория android-sdk/tools/). Но там большинство функционала deprecated (см. [ссылку](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html))

Comment: Открыл, что то показывает) После Profiler`а, не то конечно). Спасибо.

Comment: Если ответил правильно, прошу принять как решение :) Не за что!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать в Google Chrome chrome://inspect/#devices  Там довольно много опции. Выбираешь свой девайс и уже профайлишь, что нужно. Я так смотрю реквесты и респонсы на андройд 9.0, т.к профайлер в студии не хочет их открывать.

Comment: Не понял как это работает.